# Confused in starting a project in node.js with npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

Hello I am just a noob and still learning. I have already downloaded and tried the **chat** tutorial of get-started part from [socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/). Now, I am again learning from another source. What's confusing me is that, do I always have to `npm install` in the beginning of every project after writing the dependencies in the package.json? Or is there any other way? I would be very glad if you could help me understand my confusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, before running, all dependencies must be installed. So you must run `npm install`.

When developing, you can use `npm install --save <package_name>` to install a dependency *and* automatically add it to `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

NPM means Node Package Manager. It is used to manage your dependencies to other node modules dynamically thanks to a configuration file called `package.json`. This way you can easily define the exact versions you need or a mask in order to always retrieve the stable ones for instance.

The command `npm install` allows to interpret your configuration file and then download the good versions (and this recursively).